# На Wordpress не работают скрипты

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Я сверстал макет, после чего решил его натянуть на *cms wordpress*, подключил стили и скрипты в *functions.php*, подключил все через функции `wp_head()` и `wp_footer()`.

Вот содержание файла *functions.php*:

```
<?php
function wptuts_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('style-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script('menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script/menu.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script/slider.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script/carousel.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('top-button', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script/top-button.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts' );
?>
```

Стили работают, но скрипты почему-то не хотят.

Вот ошибки которые выдает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*P.S:* Без cms все скрипты работали корректно.

---

*P.S.S:* Я пытался нагуглить причину ошибок, но так и не смог ее найти.

Comment: Вы выставили зависимости и учли порядок подключения скриптов? Проверили, что все необходимые библиотеки подключены?

Comment: Один скрипт покажите для примера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть большие подозрения на то, что скрипты подключаются до того, как будет загружено дерево DOM, а их содержимое не предполагает такого.

Тут есть 2 варианта решения:

1. исправьте скрипты так, чтобы их содержимое выполнялось только после события `onLoad`
2. перенесите скрипты в `wp_footer()` (ниже приведен пример того, как это можно сделать)

   ```
   add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'action_requeue_scripts' );

   function action_requeue_scripts () {
       remove_action( 'wp_head','wp_print_scripts' );
       remove_action( 'wp_head','wp_print_head_scripts', 9 );
       remove_action( 'wp_head','wp_enqueue_scripts', 1 );

       add_action( 'wp_footer','wp_print_scripts', 5 );
       add_action( 'wp_footer','wp_enqueue_scripts', 5 );
       add_action( 'wp_footer','wp_print_head_scripts', 5 );
   }
   ```